# Node.js fs error extending

Tags: json, node.js, error-handling

I have a file moving utility on server side, 
if the target directory does not exist, the error returned is (over the wire):

```
{errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'uploads/workgroup/message.docx'}
```

The piece of code on the server side:

```
fs.rename(oldpath,newpath, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    err.message = 'Target directory does not exist.';
    return res.send(400, err);
  }
```

As you see, the `err.message` is ignored.
If I create a new error object, everything is fine:

```
fs.rename(oldpath,newpath, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    err.message = 'Target directory does not exist.';
    var err2 = new Error();
    err2.message = err.message;
    err2.code = err.code;
    err2.path = err.path;
    err2.errno = err.errno;
    return res.send(400, err2);
  }
```

I have no idea, why the original error object can not be modified. 
I tried `console.log(util.inspect(err, {showHidden: true, depth: null}));`, but it did not give much clue.

Any explanation is much appreciated!

Comment: MDN documentation says you can't modify the Error proto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/prototype

Comment: @oshnaps - Two things:  1) The OP is not modifying the Error prototype.  They're just adding an "own" property to the existing object. and 2) What I read on MDN says: ***you can use the prototype of the constructor to add properties or methods to all instances created with that constructor***,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an error object is created with an argument passed to the constructor as in:

```
var e = new Error("Some Message Here");
```

it creates an Error object that has a `.message` property that is not enumerable.  And, `JSON.stringify()` which `res.send()` uses does not include enumerable properties.  And, it stays non-enumerable even when you assign a different value to that property.

But, if you create the Error object without a message passed to the constructor and then assign the `.message` property to it like this:

```
var e = new Error();
e.message = "Some Message Here";
```

Then, the `.message` property ends up as enumerable and will be included in `JSON.stringify()`.  I have no idea why the V8 engine does it this way, but it does.

---

The enumerability of the property is configurable, so you could change it which would make it so `res.send()` would include it:

```
fs.rename(oldpath,newpath, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    Object.defineProperty(err, "message", {enumerable: true});
    err.message = 'Target directory does not exist.';
    return res.send(400, err);
  }
```

Or, you could just use your own property name which will be enumerable by default:

```
fs.rename(oldpath,newpath, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    err.reason = 'Target directory does not exist.';
    return res.send(400, err);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a clear explanation, and indeed `Object.defineProperty` do fix the json (which is sent over the wire). I marked your answer as accepted.